# What is the purpose of the electrical distribution neutral wire?

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, neutral

In US and Canada at least, the neutral wire that comes into the house is eventually connected to the local ground inside the main breaker panel.

Since it is grounded, what purpose is served by the neutral wire going to the outside supply (e.g. does it ever carry any current)?

Comment: Depends. Is your city built on top of a gigantic copper nugget, such that ground has the same resistance as actual wires?

Answer (score 3):

Many people make *far too much* of the neutral-ground bond that they see in their panel.  (the bond manifesting as neutrals and grounds on the same bar, does not help).

What is electrically accurate is these are two *totally separate systems* that pass like ships in the night, except for ONE specific bond wire that takes care of several problems and keeps neutral from floating thousands of volts above ground.  If I were king, the bond wire would be replaced with a  4-volt transformer, creating a 4-volt bias between neutral and ground.  That would force people to understand what's actually going on.

### The neutral current path.

Electricity was originally supplied to homes as +100V, 0V, and -100V.  This splitting was done to reduce *voltage drop* - the killer app for electricity was artificial lighting and motors.  Lights would go between 0V and + or - 100V.  Motors would go between +100V and -100V, giving 200V for the motor.

All light circuits used the 0V line.  And if you had 2 lights on, one on each DC pole, then power passed from +100V through both bulbs to -100V, and 0V was barely a player.  It handled only differential current.

Grounding was not a thing.

The idea was that even though loads were 100V, distributing the loads evenly across opposite poles meant that *voltage drop* behaved as if the supply was 200V. Very important since voltage drop was nearly impossible to correct in a DC system.

(100V was bumped up to 110V over the years).

When AC came along, they didn't want to rewire every home.  So they did the most expedient thing and supplied 220V AC *RMS* with a center tap giving 110V AC RMS.  Thus the same light bulbs could continue in use.

And that's how we have our system today.

Thus, neutral is a full and active "player" in power distribution, handling return current for all 120V loads.

It is one of your 3 conductors.

### The safety ground current path.

In the 1950s, safety ground started to come in. This is a completely separate system.  It flows from your house's ground rods, via the panels, out to the circuits of the home.  That is its path. It is ideal for arresting lighting and ESD *just as it is there*.

However, there was a problem.  It was possible for a "transformer leak" to float the 120V/240V output of the transformer's secondary windings  up to thousands of volts above natural earth, creating a shock risk since almost no appliance is rated for thousands of volts of electrical insulation.   We don't want that to happen. We want to FORCE the transformer secondary to a reasonable voltage to earth. How best to do this?

### The neutral-ground bond

Well, the best way is to pick any secondary wire and bond it to the earth via a grounding rod.  If you pick an end wire, then neutral is 120V to earth and the other pole is 240V to earth.  That would serve the purpose... but somewhat better would be to pick the neutral wire, forcing both poles to 120V to earth and reducing shock hazard somewhat.

- Like I say, I would bond this through a 4-volt transformer, creating a 4-volt bias between neutral and ground, and the poles would be 116V and 124V to ground. It would be more illustrative.
- However, the cost accountants disagree with me and use a simple wire for almost free, giving 0V bias and a lot of confusion.

But since we have this bonding, we have one more job for it.  If an appliance suffers a *bolted fault*, with its hot wire dead shorting against something, we'd really like that to be safety ground instead of a person.  But if it's ground, we have an opportunity. If we can get hundreds of amps to flow, we can get the circuit breaker to instant-trip, shutting down the faulty appliance.

Current does NOT want to return to ground. It wants to return to **source**.  Which for lightning is ground, but for human-made electricity is the transformer neutral.  We need to get the fault current off the ground wire and over to the neutral wire. Thus, we need the neutral-ground bond to do that *also*.

It's a busy bond.

### Ground is DIRT, for Pete's sake

One common confusion is "Why even wire a neutral wire if it's going to be at the same potential as ground? Can't we just use the earth as neutral?"

Which leads to a follow-on question: "Why even bother mining copper? Why not just wrap dirt in THHN insulation and sell it as wire?"

Because dirt is an extremely poor conductor, and is unfit to carry the high currents and low voltages that humans prefer.

If houses were wired with 48,000 volt systems where a large all electric suburban home had a 1-amp main breaker, then using dirt as the return would be practical. Unfortunately, nothing else would be lol.

But if you look into it, that's exactly what is done *for electric **distribution*** in Australia and many 3rd world countries, as SWER (Single Wire Earth Return).  A standard hack is to salvage microwave transformers, wire the 120V or 230V side to a generator, and the 10,000 volt side to a) the earth and b) a single wire going to a remote site.  At the remote site, another microwave transformer does the reverse, stepping it back down to 120V or 230V normal utility voltage.  This could barely support a microwave obviously, but easily supports iPad and laptop charging, radio, and lighting.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, neutrals carry current. In the case of the incoming neutral, it will carry the difference between the two hots. Worst case if you have no load on one hot leg, the neutral will carry the entire return current from the other hot leg.

On the other hand, if the two hot legs carry equal current, the neutral carries no current. In fact, if you have only 240 volt loads, there is no need for a neutral.

Note: this assumes you have 240 volt service where the legs are 180 degrees out of phase. It’s slightly different with 208 volt service from 3-phase power.